# WebProfiler in Silex doesn't show user

Tags: php, symfony, security, silex

I've integrated [`silex/web-profiler`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler) in a Silex app:

```
"require-dev": {
    "silex/web-profiler": "^2.0"
}
```

and configured an example firewall with form authentication:

```
// Security
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'main' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => true,
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
        'users' => array(
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '$2y$10$3i9/lVd8UOFIJ6PAMFt8gu3/r5g0qeCJvoSlLCsvMTythye19F77a'),
        ),
    )
);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array());

// Profiler
if ($app['debug']) {
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
    $app->register(new Provider\WebProfilerServiceProvider(), array(
        'profiler.cache_dir' => __DIR__.'/../cache/profiler',
        'profiler.mount_prefix' => '/_profiler', // this is the default
    ));
}
$app->boot();
```

I'm able to login with the example `admin` account and access the user in a controller, but the WebProfiler doesn't show the user tab:

[image]

Should it be additionally configured?

Comment: Can you check if you have the security bundle installed? It must be installed in ordrer to [activate the SecurityDataCollector](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler/blob/master/WebProfilerServiceProvider.php#L180)

Comment: @mTorres Thanks for the hint! Yes, security-bundle was not installed. symfony/security-bundle is a require-dev dependency to silex/web-profiler, so it didn't get installed with composer install. I had to composer require --dev symfony/security-bundle and it worked. Please add your comment as an answer and maybe elaborate a little bit. I'll accept it with pleasure :)

Comment: Done, we can close this one now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in order to show the security panel with the user information in the web debug toolbar you need to [install also the security bundle](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler/blob/master/WebProfilerServiceProvider.php#L180) (where the [SecurityDataCollector class resides](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/3.0/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DataCollector)).

So you just need to execute:

> composer require --dev symfony/security-bundle

And that should be enough.